# Proxmox VE 7.4-3 don't open console on a subdomain

Tags: nginx, proxmox

(sorry for my English) I have a proxmox running some containers, and, i haved a container running ubuntu with nginx to make a proxy reverse of my containers to my domin, like proxmox.mydomain.com, nextcloud.mydomin.com and etc. But i recenty install a mail server in a container running ubuntu 20.04(iRedMail) and this server already has have a Nginx, so a migrad my old nginx proxy to the new one. After that my proxmox.domin.com dont work any more, the page opens but the consoles dont work. But if a open the site with the ip public works(exemple: https://ip.public:8006) what can i do to resolve this problem?

```
#pveversion -v   
proxmox-ve: 7.4-1 (running kernel: 5.15.102-1-pve)
pve-manager: 7.4-3 (running version: 7.4-3/9002ab8a)
pve-kernel-5.15: 7.3-3
pve-kernel-5.15.102-1-pve: 5.15.102-1
ceph: 17.2.6-pve1
ceph-fuse: 17.2.6-pve1
corosync: 3.1.7-pve1
criu: 3.15-1+pve-1
glusterfs-client: 9.2-1
ifupdown2: 3.1.0-1+pmx4
ksm-control-daemon: 1.4-1
libjs-extjs: 7.0.0-1
libknet1: 1.24-pve2
libproxmox-acme-perl: 1.4.4
libproxmox-backup-qemu0: 1.3.1-1
libproxmox-rs-perl: 0.2.1
libpve-access-control: 7.4.1
libpve-apiclient-perl: 3.2-1
libpve-common-perl: 7.4-2
libpve-guest-common-perl: 4.2-4
libpve-http-server-perl: 4.2-3
libpve-rs-perl: 0.7.7
libpve-storage-perl: 7.4-3
libspice-server1: 0.14.3-2.1
lvm2: 2.03.11-2.1
lxc-pve: 5.0.2-2
lxcfs: 5.0.3-pve1
novnc-pve: 1.4.0-1
proxmox-backup-client: 2.4.2-1
proxmox-backup-file-restore: 2.4.2-1
proxmox-kernel-helper: 7.4-1
proxmox-mail-forward: 0.1.1-1
proxmox-mini-journalreader: 1.3-1
proxmox-widget-toolkit: 3.7.3
pve-cluster: 7.3-3
pve-container: 4.4-6
pve-docs: 7.4-2
pve-edk2-firmware: 3.20230228-4~bpo11+1
pve-firewall: 4.3-4
pve-firmware: 3.6-5
pve-ha-manager: 3.6.1
pve-i18n: 2.12-1
pve-qemu-kvm: 7.2.0-8
pve-xtermjs: 4.16.0-2
qemu-server: 7.4-4
smartmontools: 7.2-pve3
spiceterm: 3.2-2
swtpm: 0.8.0~bpo11+3
vncterm: 1.7-1
zfsutils-linux: 2.1.11-pve1
```

the nginx/proxmox.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxmox.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name proxmox.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxmox.domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxmox.domain/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localip:8006/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmtjX.png)
[When open by https://hostip:8006](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvnhh.png)

I just want to have access to my proxmox server by my subdomain.